# android- Is it possible to play swf files directly from the zip folder without unzipping it

Tags: java, android, zip

I'm trying to play swf files from a password protected zip folder. I am using (zip4j_1.3.1 library) & the following code to extract it to a seperate location then I'm playing it using webview.

```
String source = "/sdcard/Test.zip";
        String destination = "/sdcard";
        String password = "dhinesh";

        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
            if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                zipFile.setPassword(password);
            }
            zipFile.extractAll(destination);
                   mWebView.loadUrl("/sdcard/catmouse.swf");

        } catch (net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried to play file using the following code to play it directly from the zip folder itself and it is not working. Im doing this because so that it can be secured way.

```
String source = "/sdcard/Test.zip";
        String password = "dhinesh"; 

        try {
             ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
             if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                zipFile.setPassword(password);
                mWebView.loadUrl("/sdcard/Test.zip!/catmouse.swf");
            }
```

Is there any way to play the swf file from password protected zip file without unzipping it...?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the zip file format works. Even on a desktop computer, when you "directly open" a file form a zip, it's uncompressed from the archive in a temporary folder and then opened. You definitely have to unzip it first.